# Confused about std::valarray slicing (slice_array, gslice_array, mask_array and indirect_array)

Tags: c++, numeric

I want to get a `std::valarray` range that references a range of values from another `valarray` object *without* making copies of the values. [The documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operator%5B%5D/) states in relation to the index `[]` operator that I need to use a `std::slice` `std::gslice` or boolean `std::valarray` object as parameters to achieve this, in which case I'll get a `slice_array`, `gslice_array` or `mask_array` as return:

```
   slice_array<T> operator[] (slice slc);
  gslice_array<T> operator[] (const gslice& gslc);   
    mask_array<T> operator[] (const valarray<bool>& msk);
indirect_array<T> operator[] (const valarray<size_t>& ind);
```

When I look at the descriptions of these return types, they're all the same! Check out these descriptions: [slice_array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice_array/), [gslice_array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/gslice_array/),[mask_array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/mask_array/), [indirect_array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/indirect_array/).

So which should I use for which situation? I understand that `mask_array` and `indirect_array` seem more geared toward specifically picking values from a range, but what about `slice_array`/`gslice_array`?

In my case I'm thinking of going with `slice_array` because it sounds pretty much like what I'm doing (I'm slicing, right?). But I'd prefer something more concrete!

Comment: "they're all the same!" Well, they present the same public interface, which is a good thing. They differ in implementation. For example, they all provide `operator[]`, but they differ in how they determine exactly which element from the underlying `valarray` gets returned by `mySlice[0]`. You want `slice_array`. I'm not sure what you mean by "more concrete" - in what way does `slice_array` fail to meet your expectations?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no it meets my expectations just fine, they all do as far as I can tell! The reason I'm asking is because I can't tell them apart; surely they have different functions?

Comment: Of course. They differ in how the subset of the elements in the underlying `valarray` they represent is chosen: by `slice`, by `gslice`, by `valarray<bool>`, or by `valarray<size_t>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but aren't `slice` and `gslice` chosen in exactly the same way?

Comment: `gslice` is strictly more powerful than `slice`: any subset  you can express with an instance of `slice` you can also express with an instance of `gslice`, but the opposite is not true. `slice` is easier to use, for those situations where its expressive power is sufficient.